# What is the solution for mapping a large area by using computer vision for indoor navigation system?

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, augmented-reality, arkit

For using computer vision based Indoor navigation initially we need to scan the area and place the models ,objects and path.Save the map which we can load later when opening the app.The problem is when the area to be mapped is large and have several floors ,it will be difficult to scan the area with a mobile device.

Is there an alternate way to map large area?A 3d map based solution if it is there?.The problem is the device recognises the scene and place the models and objects.If I can create an exact 3d map and integrate it into unity so that I can place the objects and models in unity and create an app.So when we open the app the device scans and recognises the scene and place the objects there rather than going into the scene and mapping using mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way to get a point-cloud world map is to scan the whole area multiple times using Apple device with `ARKit` and save it as a world-mapping data to local storage.

For **Persistent AR experiences** you can save a scanned world map:

```
func writeWorldMap(_ worldMap: ARWorldMap, to url: URL) throws {
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap, 
                                         requiringSecureCoding: true)
    try data.write(to: url)
}
```

and then retrieve it when you need:

```
func loadWorldMap(from url: URL) throws -> ARWorldMap {
    let mapData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, 
                                                                   from: mapData) else { 
        throw ARError(.invalidWorldMap) 
    }
    return worldMap
}
```

In addition to it, you have to use a printed/painted visual content (a.k.a. based on images pre-trained ML model for `CoreML` and `Vision` frameworks) for detecting an exact position of a user inside that world map (you may use traffic signs for that purpose, like on the picture below).

[image]

[image]